# Angular 4 ng-template within another ng-template doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ng-bootstrap, ng-template

I am using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) component ngtabset. When I nest ng-templates I don't see anything in the view. Can someone explain why and how to resolve it?

The following works and shows me two tabs with content from both tabs visible respectively.

```
<ngb-tabset>
      <ngb-tab>
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>Tab 1</ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          This is tab 1 content
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab>
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>Tab 2</ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            This is tab 2 content
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

The following doesn't work as I don't see the content from Tab 2.

```
<ngb-tabset>
      <ngb-tab>
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>Tab 1</ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          This is tab 1 content
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab>
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>Tab 2</ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            <ng-template>This is tab 2 content</ng-template>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

Why do I need to do this? I have a custom component that accepts a TemplateReference, which needs to be displayed in the tab 2 content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said ***I have a custom component that accepts a TemplateReference***

This means you have TemplateRef variable in your component class. So instead of using ng-template, you should use ng-container and project your template in this container using ngTemplateOutlet.

```
<ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="your_template_ref_variable"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked but now, when I click between the tabs the content for both tags gets appended to the previous content 'this is tab 1' 'this is tab 1' 'this is tab 1' instead of just switching between the existing content. Everytime I click on the tab a new `<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" aria-labelledby="ngb-tab-0" id="ngb-tab-0-panel" aria-expanded="true">
 
           
        </div>` is being added

Comment: Thanks. I put together a plunker myself and I was trying to replicate it using my component but I can't replicate the issue on plunker. After debugging my code locally, I figured out it has something to do with ngOnChange and TemplateReference object is passed to it as SimpleChanges when I click on between the tabs.